# redirecting user directly to blog post after login

Tags: javascript, php

i have started a blog and created a custom url like https://myurl.com/article-1 instead of https://myurl.com/view-article?article=article-1 now my question is i want to share that url and if any one click on that link it has to redirect them to login page if not logged in and after login redirect them to the requested url using php or javascript?????

Comment: That's not a question: _"i want to share"_

Comment: also please make use of interpunctuation. Your text is hard to understand.

Comment: maybe best would be to [Start with a Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: I have started a blog and created a custom url  i.e https://myurl.com/article-1 instead of https://myurl.com/view-article?article=article-1. Now my question is,  i want to share that url and if any one click on that link it has to open login page if they are not logged in,  and after login redirect them to the requested url using php or javascript?????

Comment: i want to share page from my website  and if any one click on that link it has to open login page if they are not logged in,  and after login redirect them to the requested url using php or javascript?. the thing is if u open myurl.com by typing it into browser,  it will ask you to login and after that it will take you to index.php . but when you click that shared link it need to open login page after that redirect you to link you clicked not to index.php .  hope you can understand it now sorry for my bad english

Comment: putting a questionmark at the end of "I want to ....?" still doesn't make it a question. I understand what you want to do, but I don't know what hinders you to do that!

Answer (score 0):

May I post a picture?  This is the way that I have taken to make blogs "private."  You may add Google users to a white-list of people who can read or edit the blog.  I have this screen capture hilighted.

[Click Here to see screen capture of Google's Blogger.com Settings Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlFXF.png)